# VPS Server shoots to 900% CPU Utilisation for 10 to 15 minutes

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, cpu-usage, vcpu

I've just taken a VPS Server with Assured 1 core AMD opetron and burstable to 8 cores. RAM is 5 GB

Average Usage so far been around 1 Cpu, but at a point of time - when checked through monitoring - site was slow,
Sent mail to server admin - they replied

*I could see that the server load was very high earlier. This has been resolved now.*

05:30:02 AM 58 350 34.90 12.28 5.10

05:40:02 AM 12 309 13.77 33.58 22.60

The monitoring stats shows

> Disk Mbps write peaked to 11.1 - which otherwise remains in range of .26 to .41

After 2 hours

> Server load peaked to one minute average of 48.93 and 15 mins average of 22.67
>
> CPU Utilisation went close to 900%

My question is Despite traffic was same at 100 visitors as per analytics - what such anomality explains - once happened for disk mbps and second for cpu utilisation and server peak. What could have had happened in those 10 to 15 minutes. What are the possiblities

Comment: Too little information. Seriously. A car crashed, tell me the reason. I would someohow think disck IO would either be logfiles (which you can check, I mean web server logs) or swap space. And what is CPU utilization? How do you see this measured? Load is not CPU utilization - disc IO can cause load.

Comment: Hello, I checked server logs, could not find anything unusual in it. Server monitoring shows CPU Load - which went to 4 Vpcu at that point of time. I'm a naive in technical aspect of sites - is into business. So - wondering what could have caused the issue ?

Comment: Incompetent programming? That is regularly the issue - bad load testing and crappy business assumptions included. Sorry, there is no other answer - in a well maintained environment a technically capable admin would ask here and know how to ask this question after doing his homework. It VERY likely is some sort of user spike that bad programming or too small hardware was unable to handle.